# Parse Coefficient of an Linear equation

Tags: java, parsing, calculator, coefficients, linear-equation

In java i am trying to find the coefficients of a linear equation  to find  solution of linear equation in my calculator application  for example :

```
3x +2*(6x-3) = 2 -4x
```

what i am dying to get is the coefficients of x and the constant  in the form   `ax+b =0` ,

in this particular example

```
coefficient = 19
constant = -8
```

Please suggest a generalized idea

Comment: Should it also be able to solve this for something like `3 * x + 2 * (6 * x - 3) = 2 - 4 * x * log(sin(cos(42))^(sqrt(tan(2+atan(12))`? Just to know whether the answer should be some quick `Integer.parseInt` and `string.substring` mess, or a full-fledged computer algebra system...

Comment: @Marco13 that was funny :P But his was a good question though.

Comment: A generalized idea would be to write a grammar. Google 'antlr calculator example' for details.

Comment: For current , the above equation i asked would be enough  , can you help guys ?

Comment: Eliminate white spaces, parse character by character, calculate the values of coefficient and constant on the fly. Should be the easiest to do and understand if you never used a grammar parser before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested by my comment: This may be arbitrarily complicated, depending on *what* exactly this parser should support. There are several potentially very complex and challenging tasks involved here.

The first one is *parsing* itself. Although it's well understood and there are supporting tools for writing parsers and all, it would be tedious (and would involve some effort) to write a robust, reliable parser for these expressions *from scratch*.

The second one is *simplifying* the expression. While one could write a simple parser (or use an existing one), one might (at the first glance) think that it is necessary to perform manipulations on the generated AST in order to find the actual constant and coefficient - e.g. one could think that it would be necessary to apply the laws of distribution, find common factors, shift partial expression from one side of the equation to the other and so on.

---

Fortunately, all this is not necessary :-)

You can use an arbitrary parser to parse the expressions that are involved in the equation. One of the most well-known parsers is [JEP, the Java Expression Parser](http://www.cse.msu.edu/SENS/Software/jep-2.23/doc/website/index.html) (this is not a recommendation - I just knew it, and it seems to work well). As the name suggests, it's only an **Expression** parser, and not an **Equation** parser. But the equation can simply be split at the `=` in order to obtain two expressions that can be parsed individually.

The two expressions would not be sufficient in order to find the coefficient and constant. But here, a small (dirty?) trick comes into play: You can derive the coefficient and constants by **evaluating** these expressions. Particularly, you can once set `x=0` to determine the *constant* part of the left and right side, respectively. Then, you can set `x=1`, evaluate the resulting expression, and subtract the constant in order to obtain the *coefficient*.

From the coefficients and constants of both sides, you can compute the coefficient and constant of the whole equation. This is implemented here, as a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import org.nfunk.jep.JEP;

public class LinearEquationParser
{
    private double coefficient;
    private double constant;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        runTest("3x = 5");
        runTest("3x +2*(6x-3) = 2 -4x");
        runTest("3x + 2*(6x -sin(3))=cos(2)-4*x*log(tan(43))");
    }

    private static void runTest(String s)
    {
        System.out.println("Input: "+s);

        LinearEquationParser p = new LinearEquationParser();
        p.process(s);

        System.out.println("Coefficient: "+p.getCoefficient());
        System.out.println("Constant   : "+p.getConstant());
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void process(String s)
    {
        JEP jep = new JEP();
        jep.setImplicitMul(true);
        jep.addStandardFunctions();
        jep.addStandardConstants();
        jep.addVariable("x",  0.0);

        String s0 = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("="));
        String s1 = s.substring(s.indexOf("=")+1, s.length());

        jep.parseExpression(s0);
        if (jep.hasError())
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(jep.getErrorInfo());
        }

        jep.addVariable("x",  0.0);
        double constant0 = jep.getValue();
        jep.addVariable("x",  1.0);
        double value0 = jep.getValue();

        jep.parseExpression(s1);
        if (jep.hasError())
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(jep.getErrorInfo());
        }

        jep.addVariable("x",  0.0);
        double constant1 = jep.getValue();
        jep.addVariable("x",  1.0);
        double value1 = jep.getValue();

        constant = constant0 - constant1;
        coefficient = (value0 - constant0) - (value1-constant1);
    }

    public double getCoefficient()
    {
        return coefficient;
    }

    public double getConstant()
    {
        return constant;
    }

}
```

The output is, as desired:

```
Input: 3x = 5
Coefficient: 3.0
Constant   : -5.0

Input: 3x +2*(6x-3) = 2 -4x
Coefficient: 19.0
Constant   : -8.0

Input: 3x + 2*(6x -sin(3))=cos(2)-4*x*log(tan(43))
Coefficient: 15.7024963786418
Constant   : 0.13390682042740798
```